# Android - Overriding a Style per Theme

Tags: android, styles, android-theme, android-styles

Is there a way to change a style based on what theme is is set on an activity? for example, suppose my activity has a textview with a style set to TextViewStyle

```
<TextView
   style="@style/TextViewStyle"        
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Text"/>
```

This is my TextViewStyle

```
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    </style>
```

In my Styles.xml I have two themes

```
 <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

   </style>


   <style name="AppThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Material">

   </style>
```

Now, when I have my theme set to Dark, I want this theme to override some values I set in my TextViewStyle. How could I do this? I tried the following, but It does not work

```
    <!-- Override TextViewStyle style for AppThemeLight-->
            <style name ="AppThemeLight.TextBlockStyle" parent="@style/TextBlockStyle">
                <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_purple</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
            </style>
<!-- Override TextViewStyle style for AppThemeDark-->
            <style name ="AppThemeDark.TextBlockStyle" parent="@style/TextBlockStyle">
                <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_green</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
            </style>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok here is how I achieved this, 1 hour after posting the question! Might be helpful for someone else!

First in attrs.xml I defined the following :

```
 <attr name="textBlockStyle" format="reference"/>
```

Then in the style.xml

```
<style name="TextBlockStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="textBlockStyle">@style/AppThemeLightTextBlockStyle</item>
    </style>


     <style name="AppThemeDark" parent="android:Theme.Material">
         <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="textBlockStyle">@style/AppThemeDarkTextBlockStyle</item>
    </style>



    <!-- Override TextBlockStyle style for AppThemeLight -->
    <style name ="AppThemeLightTextBlockStyle" parent="@style/TextBlockStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_purple</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Override MyButton style for AppThemeDark -->
    <style name ="AppThemeDarkTextBlockStyle" parent="@style/TextBlockStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/my_green</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
    </style>
```

Notice how I use the attribute I defined to reference a style

```
<item name="textBlockStyle">@style/AppThemeLightTextBlockStyle</item>
```

Finally, on my element I set the style like this "style="?textBlockStyle" :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?textBlockStyle"
        android:text="...."
        android:gravity="center" />
```

When I set my activity theme to Dark or Light, the correct textButtenStyle will be used

Answer (score 0):

Add a textStyle element to your activity style and make it equal to the desired style, then when the activity is loaded all textViews inside will have the style specified inside its theme unless you override it in your textView

Comment: hmm not sure I get what you mean.... could you provide a little example? I want to be able to override a default textStyle per theme.

Comment: Try something like

<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/yourTextViewStyle</item> 

Inside your activity style

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/yourTextViewStyle</item>
```

Inside your activity style